# Understanding the meaning of $p_{01}$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

In the following [link](https://www.unilim.fr/pages_perso/stephane.vinatier/Articles/arrangements.pdf) for the historical problem (first part): in how many "regions" a finite set A of lines intersect the plane for the first he defines:

$p_{0}$ : is the number of intersection points of $A$ (without multiplicity)

$p_{1}$ : $|A|$ is the cardinal of $A$

$p_{01}$ : is the number of pairs consisting of a line of $A$ and one of its intersection points

If anyone can explain to me the meaning of $p_{01}$ because even with the following figure I'm having a hard time ^^.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p_{01}$ is the number of "flags" in the configuration: an ordered tuple of a line and an intersection which the line partakes in. Three of the lines in the diagram have two intersections and the fourth has three intersections, so $p_{01}=9$ here.